# How to use global properties for http parameters in SOAPUI?

Tags: api, soap, soapui

I am setting up a lot of http requests for a REST api. Many of the requests require the same parameters in the URL (`public_key`, `auth_token`, etc). I was trying to set these as a global property, but I cannot figure out how to reference them within each request. I tried `${poperty_name}` but that did not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive it by opening your parent resource and then add `Resource Parameters` to it. After that you can see the params in requests
[image: add params]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, you should specify level of property (Project, TestSuite, TestCase). So, if you define project level property then you need call it as `${#Project#property_name}`

http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html#4-example-n-centralized-endpoint